# how to get the date using moment js from relative time?

Tags: date, momentjs

how can i convert this relative time to date ?

3 hours, 19 minutes ago
1 day, 1 hour ago
06 Jan 2017

for 2 days ago i can use this moment js code :

```
moment($(elem).find('.date').text(),'DD MMMM YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

so help me to get the date for today and yesterday time

Comment: Can you explain what is your goal better? What is your input and what should be your output? What you tried so far? See here to learn how to provide  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @VincenzoC thanks for your reply. 
if you see the 06 Jan 2017, if i use the code , it will change to 2017-01-06.

so what my goal is to set that 3 hours,19 minutes ago to 2017-01-09 
also 1 day 1 hour ago to 2017-01-08